# Indexed retrieval SortedDictionary<>

Tags: c#

I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z658b67.aspx) that SortedDictionary does not allow indexed retrieval unlike SortedList.
Then how can I get the `nameAddr["C"]` correctly in the following code snippet?

```
        SortedDictionary<string, string> nameAddr = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        nameAddr.Add("X", "29");
        nameAddr.Add("A", "30");
        nameAddr.Add("C", "44");           

        Console.WriteLine(nameAddr["C"]);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's indexing by *key*. SortedList allows indexing by "index of key", e.g. `nameAddr.Values[1]` would return "44".

(The collection doesn't allow indexing of name/value pair, just of each of `Keys` and `Values` separately.)

For example:

```
var list = new SortedList<string, string>
{
    { "X", "29" },
    { "A", "30" },
    { "C", "44" },
};

Console.WriteLine(list.Keys[1]); // Prints "C"
Console.WriteLine(list.Values[1]); // Prints "44"
```

Answer (score 7):

SortedList internally uses an array as the data structure for storage and then just sorts the array as needed to keep the items in order.  Since it uses an array the items can be accessed using a numeric index like you would for any array.

SortedDictionary internally uses a red-black binary search tree to keep the items in order.  The concept is completely different.  There is no array and no analog for retrieving the items by a numeric index.  Your only option is to use the key portion of the key-value pair that was added to the dictionary.

With that said.  Your code looks correct to me.  That is the only way to retrieve items from the dictionary (other than using than Values collection, but that will not give you the numeric indexing ability either).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it.

Had the same problem when working on code that was keeping track of TimeSeries objects in a collection called RawTSeries.

Needed to access them by name which was a string and by index which was an int.

Simply added an additional List of Strings to the code along with the SortedDictionary:

```
    **SortedDictionary<string, TimeSeries> RawTSeries = new();
    List<string> RawTSeriesKeys = new();**
```

Created three helper functions as follows:

```
    **private void AddToRawTSeries(string tsName, TimeSeries timeSeries)
    {
        RawTSeries.Add(tsName, timeSeries);
        RawTSeriesKeys.Add(tsName);
    }
    TimeSeries? GetFromRawTSeries(string key)
    {
        if(RawTSeries.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return RawTSeries[key];
        }
        return null;
    }
    TimeSeries? GetFromRawTSeries(int index)
    {
        if((index >= 0)&&(index<RawTSeries.Count))
        {
            return RawTSeries[RawTSeriesKeys[index]];
        }
        return null;
    }**
```

Note that GetFromRawTSeries is overloaded so it works with either a string or an int. In both cases if it fails it returns null.

This was all I needed so I left it like this. My app never removed TimeSeries so I didn't have to coordinate removals but it would be easy to make sure that the given key was removed from both RawTSeries and RawTSeriesKey.

This whole thing could be wrapped up in a class called IndexedSortedDictionary but the three helper functions above were all I needed.

By the way GetFromRawTSeries is O(ln) when using strings or ints.
If you used Dictionary instead of SortedDictionary it would be roughly O(1) with strings or ints.

Happy Programming!